# Modify an old string into an new string from a file

Tags: c

Say I have a birthday that is written as `04251993` in some file that

I want to format it as `04/25/1993`

I'm assuming that I should make an empty string, or modify the old string into the new string.

I'm not quite sure of how to do that: need some help on writing the function.
 I started it out like this.

the first two chars need to be the month with a slash after, 2 more chars with a slash after and then lasty 4 more chars to put out the year.

```
void timef(char str[]){
printf("%c, str[0]) ?
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?. Why not `char newdate[11] = "";`  to hold the new date. You can easily pick out the month, day, year and add to `newdate` with `strncpy (newdate, olddate, 2);` `newdate[2] = '/';`, `strncpy (newdate + 3, olddate + 3, 2);` `newdate[5] = '/';` and finally `strncpy (newdate + , olddate + 4, 4);` Give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Make a character array large enough on the heap. Then go through the
characters and insert the slashes.  Use fputs to place it in a file.  Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a function that is general or one that only performs an operation within set bounds. For this answer, let's just work on the latter. This means, I'll assume your string is always a fixed size of 9 chars (including '\0') and the packing of the data is "mm/dd/yyyy".
From there, you just need to work out how much larger the new string needs to be, and that's originalString + 2 chars, so you need a new array of 11 characters.

```
char newDate[11] = "";
```

Then you need to loop through the contents of the original string array and place each character into the new array, as well as adding the slashes as you go. So something like this:

```
int main()
{
  int newSize = 11;
  char oldDate[9] = "04231993";
  char newDate[11] = ""; 

  for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < newSize && j < oldSize; i++, j++){
    if(i == 2){
       newDate[i] = '/';
       i++;
      }
    if(i == 5){
      newDate[i] = '/';
      i++;
    }
    newDate[i] = oldDate[j];
  }
  printf("%s", newDate);
}
```

That's REALLY simple and only to illustrate the basic concept. I would recommend working on your own, more robust version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%.*s"` to scan the original string and then write to a new one

```
const char *src = "04251993";
char dest[11];
if (strlen(src) >= 8) {
  sprintf(dest, "%.2s/%.2s/%.4s", src, src + 2, src + 4);
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Hmmm I did write this before seeing your nearly identical [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647419/modify-an-old-string-into-an-new-string-from-a-file/43647679#comment74343123_43647419)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You mis-understand.  I am not complaining, I am complementing you on that we both _independently_ made similar - good code.  I did not want you to think I posted your idea without crediting you.